# Scala Ordering, Ordered, and View Bound

Tags: scala

I am writing the following code to illustrate the problem:

```
def max[T <% Ordered[T]](a: T, b: T) = {
  val c = a.compare(b)
  if (c > 0) a else b
}

def min[T <% Ordering[T]](a: T, b: T) = {
    val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
    val c = ord.compare(a, b)
    if (c > 0) b else a
}

println(s"max is ${max(10, 20)}")
implicit val intOrdering = new Ordering[Int] {
  override def compare(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x - y
}
println(s"min is ${min(10, 20)}")
```

The `max` method works well, while the `min` method doesn't, complaining  `No implicit Ordering defined for T` even though I defined the `intOrdering`, it still complains.

I would ask why `Ordered` works, but `Ordering` doesn't here, even if I have provided the implicit definition for the `Ordering[Int]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ordered` and `Ordering` are semantically different. An `Ordered[T]` is an object that supports comparisons against other `Ordered[T]`s, while an `Ordering[T]` is a single object that is a collection of functions able to compare ordinary `T`s.

This difference is reflected in the two types of bounds you need to use here. The view bound `[T <% Ordered[T]]` means that there needs to be an implicit function `T => Ordered[T]` somewhere in scope. This function is the implicit conversion `intWrapper(Int): RichInt`. These `RichInt`s directly support comparisons between themselves via the comparison methods.

However, `def min[T <% Ordering[T]]...` can't work. This requires a `T => Ordering[T]`, or a function from values of a type to orderings on that type. For some types this might exist, but for most, like `Int`, it won't.

The other kind of bound is the context bound, `T: Ordering`, which is what you must use in `min`. A context bound of this form requests an implicit `Ordering[T]`,  that is, `def min[T: Ordering](a: T, b: T)` takes two `T`s as arguments, and also one implicit `Ordering[T]` that defines how they are ordered.

In mathier language: A *view bound* is of the form `Left <% Right` for some types `Left` and `Right` of kind `*`, leading to the creation of an implicit parameter of type `Left => Right`. A *context bound* is of the form `Left: Right` for some type `Left` of some kind `k` and some type `Right` of kind `k -> *`, leading to the creation of an implicit parameter of type `Right[Left]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `view bound` used in your `max` method is really just a short-cut for:

```
def max[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit ord: T => Ordered[T]) = {
  val c = a.compare(b)
  if (c > 0) a else b
}
```

`Ordering` requires an implicit value (as opposed to an implict function for `Ordered`) for your `min` method as follows, thus `view bound` isn't applicable:

```
def min[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = {
  val c = ord.compare(a, b)
  if (c > 0) b else a
}
```

Expressing the above in the form of `context bound` yields the following:

```
def min[T: Ordering](a: T, b: T) = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
  val c = ord.compare(a, b)
  if (c > 0) b else a
}
```